# Who are the seven shepherds at the end of Maoz Tzur?

Tags: sources-mekorot, chanuka, song-poetry

The song [Maoz Tzur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%27oz_Tzur) ends with the line

> raise up the Seven Shepherds

Who are the seven shepherds referenced?

Please cite sources.

Comment: Related answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78501/7303

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many different traditions about who these individuals are precisely.

Radak to [Micah 5:4:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_Micah.5.4.3/he/Radak_on_Nach?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states that the seven shepherds are David, Seth, Chanoch, Methuselah, Avraham, Yaacov and Moshe.

> ורבותינו ז"ל אמרו מאן ננהו שבעה רועים דוד באמצע שת וחנוך ומשותלח בימינו אברהם ויעקב ומשה משמאלו ומאן נינהו שמנה נסיכי אדם ישי שאול ושמואל עמוס וצפניה חזקיה אליהו ומשיח:

This listing follows what is found in Otzar HaMidrashim, [Sefer HaMa'asim 1:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim,_The_Book_of_Tales.1.15/he/Otzar_Midrashim,_New_York,_1915?lang=bi) which says:

> אלו הם שבעה רועים: ודוד באמצע, אדם שת מתושלח בימינו אברהם יעקב ומשה בשמאלו, יצחק יושב ומשמר פתחה של גיהנם להציל בניו מדינה של גיהנם. ואלו הם שמונה נסיכי אדם, ישי שאול שמואל עמוס צפניה חזקיה אליהו ומשיח.

Another variation of this is found in Otzar HaMidrashim, [Sheva Chuppot, 29](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim,_Chuppah_of_Eliyahu,_Seven_Chupot_or_Eliyahu's_Chuppah.31/he/Otzar_Midrashim,_New_York,_1915?lang=bi) which says the seven shepherds are Adam, Seth, Enosh, Methuselah, Avraham, Yaacov and Moshe. David is not counted as one of the seven.

> כ״ט) שבעה רועים הם, ודוד באמצע: אדם שת אנוש מתושלח בימינו, אברהם ויעקב ומשה משמאלו. ויצחק היכן הלך? אלא הוא יושב על פתח גיהנם ומציל בניו מדינה של גיהנם.

This also follows the [Kol Bo 118:55](https://www.sefaria.org/Kol_Bo.118.55/he/Kol_Bo_1547_Venice_Unknown_Publisher?lang=bi) which says:

> שבעה רועים הם, אדם שת אנוש מתושלח מימינו אברהם יעקב ומשה משמאלו ויצחק הכן הלך אלא הוא יושב על פתח גיהנם ומציל בניו מדינה של גיהנם:

The [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef 1:618:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.618.11/he/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef_-_Torat_Emet_357?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) reports in the name of the Zohar that they are Avraham, Yitzchok, Yaacov, Moshe, Aharon, Yosef and David.

> מבואר בזוהר הקדוש (פר' אמור דף קג:), שהוד קדושת שבעה אושפיזין עליאין קדישין, אבות העולם, שבעת הרועים, אברהם יצחק יעקב משה אהרן יוסף ודוד

The Zohar being quoted is from parshat Emor 3:103b:8 but this seems to be contrary to the teaching of [Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai quoted in Shir HaShirim Rabbah 8:9:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.8.9.3/he/Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which follows the view found in Sukkah 52b.

This view also appears to be what is brought by Rabbi Chaim of Tchernovitz in [Be'er Mayim Chayim to Bereshit 21:28:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Be'er_Mayim_Chaim,_Genesis.21.28.3/he/Be'er_Mayim_Chaim,_Jerusalem_1991.?lang=bi) which says:

> או אפשר שרמז בשבע האלו על כניסת דוד המלך בירושלים כי הוא הסיר העורים והפסחים, והוא היה הרועה השביעי אשר הקים הקב"ה לישראל שבעה רועים והם אברהם יצחק יעקב יוסף משה אהרן ודוד הוא השביעי והוא הסיר העורים וגו'.

In this case, Aharon HaKohen is included as one of seven. This would seem to be in consideration of Yoma 5a which brings the necessity of Aharon in re-establishing the service in the Temple.

[Pirkei Hechalot Rabbati 37:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Hechalot_Rabbati.37.2/he/Wertheimer_edition?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) actually emphasizes the confusion by listing ten people as the seven shepherds.

> ויוצאין עמו שבעה רועים ושמונה נסיכי אדם **דוד באמצע אדם שת אנוש ומתושלח ומימינו אברהם יצחק ויעקב משה ואהרן משמאלו** שמנה נסיכי אדם שאול ושמואל עמוס וצפניה ואליהו ומלכי צדק וישי וחזקיהו

The [Malbim to Micah 5:4:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Micah.5.4.1/he/Malbim_on_Micah--Wikisource?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that in the final redemption the seven shepherds refer to the enemies of Israel.

> כמו שפרשתי שם, יבואו אז שבעה רועים, שהם מצרים, עילם, משך, תובל, אדום, נסיכי צפון, צידוני

Answer (score 8):

The reference is to [Michah 5:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1805.htm#4). The Talmud ([Sukkah 52b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.52b.13?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)) identifies them as King David in the middle, Adam, Seth, and Methuselah on his right, and Abraham, Jacob and Moses on his left.